# BaseAdapter causing EditText to not work

Tags: android, android-edittext, baseadapter, android-gallery

Whenever I use a base adapter to add a view to a gallery it causes the `EditText` from within the view to not allow text input, it focuses and the keyboard appears but when I enter text it doesn't appear. The `EditText` type is `numberDecimal`.

I have tried setting the content view of `MainActivity` to `ap_overview_add` and the `EditText` works fine.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.mwapps.baseadaptertest.MainActivity">

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:padding="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ap_overview_add.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/ap_overview_add_LL"
    android:gravity="center">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/ap_et_add"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/abc_secondary_text_material_light"
            android:imeOptions="actionSend"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_weight=".75"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="300"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Gallery gallery;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
        gallery.setAdapter(new GalleryImageAdapter(this));
    }
}
```

**GalleryImageAdapter.java**

```
public class GalleryImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        Context mContext;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public GalleryImageAdapter(Context context)
        {
            mContext = context;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        // Override this method according to your need
        public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            View tab;
            tab = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ap_overview_add, viewGroup, false);

            return tab;
        }
}
```

**I've looked at other questions similar and nothing has worked, including trying to change the `softinput` mode, what is causing the text to not be entered?**

**Edit: If the inputType is changed to text it allows input**

**Edit 2: If the inputtype is set to numberDecimal, numbers cannot be entered but things like commas can be, so it looks like it's not accepting numbers**

Comment: what about change your the View from Gallery to `HorizontalScrollView` or `RecyclerView`

Comment: @hakim I chose gallery because I wanted the set positions effect, where you swipe and it goes to the next item instead of keeps scrolling... It's just this one problem

Comment: in that case you can use `ViewPager` as suggested in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html

Comment: @hakim I guess that's what I get for following an outdated tutorial :) Just implemented the ViewPager and working perfectly now. Thanks. Feel free to make an official answer.

Comment: awesome :)
you're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ViewPager instead of Gallery as suggested in developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html
to make it work